# Replace/remove everything between two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

How can I remove everything between `H` and `S` so that the outcome would be `ABCDEFGHSTUVWXYZ`?

Comment: Just use `ABCDEFGHSTUVWXYZ`. Read between the words: rephrase your question. Do you want every letter between H and S to be removed? Are the first and last letter variable?

Comment: I can't just use `ABCDEFGHSTUVWXYZ`, this was only an example. Obviously I know removing it manually is an option.

Comment: Yes, but if you provide a less-simple example (unless your use-case really *is* that simple) it might help us to provide you with a better/more-applicable solution to your problem.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```js
var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
console.log(  alphabet.replace(/H.*S/, 'HS')  )
```

Or just:

```
var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHSTUVWXYZ";
```

Comment: Hello, I have HTML source from which i need to remove all script tags. I have tried below code but it also removes code between 2 instance.  Code: ``'Hello this is <script> demo </script> that you  <script> demo </script>  <style>know</style>'.replace(/<script>.*<\/script>/, '')``
Result: ``Hello this is   <style>know</style>``
Expected: ``Hello this is  that you <style>know</style>``

Comment: @Nilay You should ask new questions instead of commenting on other ones. I'll try to answer here though. You really should never do stripping of `<script>` tags. That is a very bad practice for security reasons. There is just way too much that can go wrong. What if the original code has `<scr<script></script>ipt>alert('bad');` in it? What about: `<img src=":" onerror="alert('bad');" />`?

Comment: @Nilay Instead you should whitelist specific tags and attributes that are allowed, or better use **BBCode**, or even better **Markdown**. I'm sure that in whatever language you're using, you can find some library for compiling Markdown to HTML.

Comment: @Nilay As an aside, to get the output you wanted you should make your regex `.*` non-greedy by changing it to `.*?` and make your regex global with the `g` flag: `/<script>.*?<\/script>/g`, but please don't do this. Know that the two examples I showed to get around that and get a script to run are not the only two. There are thousands and you will never be able to get them all. Trying to do so will be an endless battle and people will constantly find ways around it.

Comment: Thanks @paulpro, I was tried ``/<script>.*?<\/script>/g`` but not worked well as expected! Because if HTML's body's first line is script and the last line is also script then it was removing all content. So I have used jQuery to remove all script elements form entire DOM.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have multiple occurrences of H and S in the String, it won't work as necessarily expected. It will take the first H and the last S, and replace everything in between (including other H's and S's) with HS. If you want to avoid this behavior, try this regex that I just made on [regex101](https://regex101.com) which seems to be working: `H([^HS]{1,})S`. It essentially replaces any sequence of chars that are not H or S, between an H and an S.

Answer (score 11):

```
var strippedAlphabet = alphabet.replace(/H.*S/, 'HS');
```

Comment: `"___H___S_____H__S____".replace(/H.*S/, 'HS')` isn't as the expected output: `___HS____HS____`

Comment: @vsync I was just experimenting on regex101 and figured out this regex which seems to work properly and produce the expected output: `H([^HS]{1,})S`. I tested it with the case in your comment and it produced the expected output. Just leaving it here in case anyone else needs it. Obviously I can't post it as an answer since this question has been closed, though :(