# Match all text within two given markers

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Let's say I have two custom javascript comments.

Opening: `//<!-` and closing: `//!>`.

I want to replace everything in between these markers, and also the markers.

```
//<!- directiveDecoratorComment
    (function directiveDecorator() {
        if (typeof(angular) == 'undefined') return;
        var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app]');
        var appName = appElement.getAttribute('ng-app');
        if (typeof(appName) == 'undefined') return;
        var app = angular.module(appName);
        angular.forEach(app._invokeQueue, function(value, key) {
            if (value[1] == 'directive') {
                var directiveName = value[2][0];
                app.config(function($provide) {
                  $provide.decorator(directiveName + 'Directive', function($delegate) {
                    var directive = $delegate[0];
                    console.log("Decorating:",directiveName,'on',appName,'template now ==',"/views/" + directive.templateUrl);
                    directive.templateUrl = "/views/" + directive.templateUrl;
                    return $delegate;
                  });
                });
            }
        });
    }());

    //!>
```

So this would essentially become and empty string javascript file.

Here's what I've tried.

```
string.replace(/([//<])(.+\n*?)([//!>])/g, '');
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/rQ1yI3/1) ?

Comment: Using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10689837/3928341), this seems to work: `str.replace(/\/\/<\!-.*\/\/\!>/g, '');`

Comment: Please read up on the meaning of a character class (`[]`) in JavaScript regexps. You could start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/(\/\/<!-)([^\/]*(?:\/(?!\/!>)[^\/]*)*)(\/\/!>)/g
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uP0tW7/1)

The regex is based on the *unroll-the-loop* technique.

- `(\/\/<!-)` - match and capture literal `//<!-`
- `([^\/]*(?:\/(?!\/!>)[^\/]*)*)` - match and capture anything but `//!>` (unrolling the loop here means we match any characters but `/` with `[^\/]*` and then match zero or more groups of `/` that is not followed with `/!>` and then again any number of any characters but `/`)
- `(\/\/!>)` - match and capture `//!>`

Note that you may get rid of capture groups if you are not making use of them.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this:

```
string.replace(/(\/\/\<\!\-)((.*\n)*.*)(\/\/\!\>)/, '')
```

Comment: This one is faster: [`(\/\/<!-)([^\/]*(?:\/(?!\/!>)[^\/]*)*)(\/\/!>)`](https://regex101.com/r/uP0tW7/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yours is the only one which has actually worked with the javascript replace method for me. Thankyou!

Comment: I will post it then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a look-ahead, using non-greedy matching:

```
/\/\/<!-[\s\S]*?\/\/!>/
 ^^^^^^^                    MATCH OPENING //<!-
        ^^^^^^^             ANYTHING IN BETWEEN
               ^^^^^^^      CLOSING //!>
```

The `\s\S` is to match newlines.