# Remove the string between two {{ and }} javaScript

Tags: javascript

I have HTML code and it have some of Angular variable({{ variable }}) in it. I want to remove all the double curly baskets and text in between it using JavaScript.

**Input String**

```
"<p>this is some{{name}}</p><div>some text {{ secondvariable1 }}</div> <div>some deferent text {{ secondvariable2 }}</div>";
```

**Output string**

```
"<p>this is some</p><div>some text </div> <div>some deferent text </div>";
```

Please help. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: const withSpaces = "<p>this is some{{name}}</p><div>some text {{ secondvariable1 }}</div> <div>some deferent text {{ secondvariable2 }}</div>";

const abc = withSpaces.replace(/(?={{).*(?=}})/g, '');
console.log(abc);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace/remove everything between two characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689784/replace-remove-everything-between-two-characters)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Input string
const inputString = "<p>this is some{{name}}</p><div>some text {{ secondvariable1 }}</div> <div>some deferent text {{ secondvariable2 }}</div>";

// Use regex to remove all instances of {{ variable }} patterns
const outputString = inputString.replace(/\{\{.*?\}\}/g, '');

console.log(outputString);
```

Comment: what sense in providing the same solution as already posted?

Comment: Sorry bro when I was writing the solution during that you also posted the same before me and when I posted the solution and page refreshed I noticed that you have already posted it

Answer (score -1):

Use a regular expression with `g` flag:

```js
const str ="<p>this is some{{name}}</p><div>some text {{ secondvariable1 }}</div> <div>some deferent text {{ secondvariable2 }}</div>";

const result = str.replace(/\{\{.*?\}\}/g, '');

console.log(result);
```